# R- How do I make a loop function to extract data and paste in a new data frame

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame consisting of two columns ("Cam_Trap_Days" and "Genus"), where Cam_Trap_Days indicates a particular day and the genus that were present at the observation.

```
structure(list(Cam_Trap_Days = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 25, 
25, 25, 26, 26, 28, 29, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 36, 37, 
37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 41, 42, 42, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 
46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 596, 596, 597, 597, 598, 
598, 598, 599, 599, 599, 599, 599, 600, 601, 601, 601, 602, 602, 
602, 604, 605, 605, 605, 606, 606, 627, 627, 633, 633, 634, 634
), Genus = structure(c(9L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 
8L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 
6L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 11L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 
12L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 11L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 
11L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
10L), .Label = c("", "Apodemus", "Columba", "Fringilla", "Homo", 
"Meles", "Muntiacus", "Oryctolagus", "Phasianus", "Sciurus", 
"Turdus", "Vulpes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 98L
), class = "data.frame")
```

My aim is to create a function that goes through this data frame, to extract the presence of each Genus on each camera trap day and paste as a presence (i.e. 1) on a new data frame, which is in the following format (number of rows for CamDays is 635):

```
  CamDays Phasianus Oryctolagus Meles Apodemus Turdus Vulpes Fringilla Columba Muntiacus Sciurus Homo
1        0         0           0     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
2        1         0           0     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
3        2         0           0     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
```

I would like in the new data frame that each Genus to have a value of 1 if present on a particular Cam_Trap_Days with the rest of the genera remaining as a 0. The example below is how I would like it to look (if only Phasianus and Oryctolagus were present at CamDay 0).

```
  CamDays Phasianus Oryctolagus Meles Apodemus Turdus Vulpes Fringilla Columba Muntiacus Sciurus Homo
1        0         1           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code in base R that accomplishes your task:

```
extractdata <- lapply(unique(df$Cam_Trap_Days), function(X) lapply(unique(df$Genus), function(Y)  length(which(df$Genus== Y & df$Cam_Trap_Days == X))))
df_new <- matrix(unlist(extractdata),nrow = length(extractdata),byrow = T)
row.names(df_new) <- unique(df$Cam_Trap_Days)
colnames(df_new) <- unique(df$Genus)
```

Edit: 
Here's an slightly different code that skips a step but results in the same output.

```
df_new <- t(sapply(unique(df$Cam_Trap_Days), function(X) lapply(unique(df$Genus), function(Y)  length(which(df$Genus== Y & df$Cam_Trap_Days == X)))))
row.names(df_new) <- unique(df$Cam_Trap_Days)
colnames(df_new) <- unique(df$Genus)
```

Output:

```
> df_new
    Phasianus Oryctolagus Meles Apodemus Turdus Vulpes Fringilla Columba Muntiacus Sciurus Homo
0           1           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
1           0           1     1        1      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
2           0           1     1        0      1      1         1       0         0       0    0
3           0           1     1        0      1      0         0       0         0       0    0
17          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
18          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
19          0           0     1        1      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
20          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
21          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       1         0       0    0
22          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
23          0           1     1        0      0      0         0       1         0       0    0
24          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
25          0           0     1        0      0      1         0       1         0       0    0
26          0           1     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
28          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
29          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         1       0    0
30          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
31          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
32          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
33          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
34          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
35          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
36          0           0     1        0      1      0         0       0         0       0    0
37          0           0     1        0      0      1         0       0         0       0    0
38          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       1         0       0    0
39          0           1     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
40          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
41          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
42          0           0     1        0      0      1         0       0         0       0    0
43          0           0     0        0      0      0         0       1         0       0    0
44          0           0     1        0      1      1         0       0         0       0    0
45          0           0     1        0      1      1         0       0         0       0    0
46          0           0     1        0      1      1         0       0         1       0    0
47          0           0     0        0      1      0         0       0         0       0    0
49          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
50          0           0     0        0      0      1         0       0         0       0    0
51          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
52          0           0     1        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
596         1           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
597         1           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
598         1           1     0        0      0      1         0       0         0       0    0
599         0           1     0        1      1      1         0       0         0       1    0
600         0           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
601         0           1     0        0      1      0         0       0         0       1    0
602         1           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         1       0    0
604         0           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
605         1           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       1    0
606         1           1     0        0      0      0         0       0         0       0    0
627         0           0     0        1      0      0         0       0         0       1    0
633         0           0     0        1      0      0         0       0         0       0    1
634         0           0     0        1      0      0         0       0         0       1    0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code runs fine and returns a table, but the data points it returns  are  wrong. From my data for the row labelled 0 for example, only Phasianus and  Oryctolagus should have 1 while the rest should be 0,while the row labelled 1 should have 1s for Meles, Oryctolagus and Apodemus, with the remainder of that row having 0s. Any more insight would be great. Thanks Again

Comment: Good catch, I forgot to specify `byrow = T` in the matrix call. I have edited my answer to include this and updated the output as well. If this answer worked for you please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: @Sam I've also added a shortened version that results in the same output.